# apt-get install приводит к ошибке 404 not found

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Есть Ubuntu 13.04, работает в виртуалке Parallels на OS X

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 13.04 \n \l
```

Пытался установить хоть что-нибудь с помощью apt-get, попытки завершились одинаково неуспешно. Начал с обновления apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Выдает достаточно много вот таких строк:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

Пытаюсь установить, например, zsh:

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install zsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  zsh-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  zsh
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,821 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  zsh
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main zsh amd64 5.0.0-2ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zsh/zsh_5.0.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Проблемный IP пингуется нормально:

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ ping 91.189.91.24
PING 91.189.91.24 (91.189.91.24) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.91.24: icmp_req=1 ttl=128 time=183 ms
...
```

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

как можно увидеть по адресу http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, там уже нет каталога `raring`.

и, действительно, согласно [таблице выпусков](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life), поддержка версии 13.04 завершена более полутора лет назад.

если эта версия чем-то очень дорога, то можно заменить адрес зеркала на «кладбище уже никому не нужного кода»: во всех файлах `/etc/apt/sources.list*` заменить `archive.ubuntu.com` (и `security.ubuntu.com`) на `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

это можно сделать такой, например, командой:

```
$ sudo sed -i -r 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?(archive|security).ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

после чего, естественно, нужно обновить список пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

---

но я бы рекомендовал скачать установочный образ посвежее.

Comment: Да уж, всё оказалось просто. Конечно, буду ставить свежий.